# Seed numpy.random.RandomState with hashlib hash

Tags: python, numpy, random, hashlib

I want to seed numpy.random.RandomState instance with an hashlib generated hash to have pseudorandom source always generating same values for same input data. When I try to do that this way:

```
hash = sha256(some_data)
RandomState(seed=hash.digest())
```

I get:

```
ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array
```

I could do `map(ord, hash.digest())` but I don't know if it is right solution. Should I do that or will I lose randomness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>First of all, the random state seed is a 32-bit unsigned integer, so it will not be able to use the full 256-bit hash you are generating.</s>

Thanks to the commenter below for pointing out that the seed can be an array of 32-bit (unsigned) integers; you can convert the hash to such an array as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from hashlib import sha256

data = np.random.rand(1000)
hash = sha256(data)
seed = np.frombuffer(hash.digest(), dtype='uint32')

rstate = np.random.RandomState(seed)
```

Comment: It can also take an array of 32-bit integers as well. `seed = np.frombuffer(hash.digest(), dtype=np.uint32)`